# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 380

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp at line 380

```
377: <td width="65%" valign="top">
378: <c:if test="${pName ne null}">
379: <div width="100%" valign="top" align="center">
380: <jsp:include page="${pName}"/>
381: <%-- <jsp:include page="common/UserProfile.htm."/>--%>
```

Hi I get error above jsp page. somthing wrong at line no 380. what changes required please suggest me . thanks in advance

Comment: Check the variable pName - what is the Page name..

Comment: Don't post same question again...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you replace ${pName} with a fixed file name to see if it can work.Then you will know
 if it is the el expression that causes the error.